# Timestamp looks correct but appears wrong on ggplot2

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a time series of CO2 data with a UNIX timestamp that looks like this: `1658759863`

e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(timestamp=seq(1653998631,1663998631,10),co2_ppm=runif(1000001))
```

I then convert to POSIXct and filter data only after 11:52:51

```
    df <- df%>% 
  mutate(timestamp=as.POSIXct(timestamp,origin="1970-01-01",tz = "GMT"))%>%
  filter(timestamp>"2022-07-28 11:52:51" )

attr(df$timestamp,"tzone")

[1] "GMT"
```

When I filter it to only plot value after "11:52:00", it returns after "10:52:00"

[image]

why?

Comment: Seems like a timezone issue to me. Your timestamps are defined as GMT, what is your local timezone `dplyr::filter()` seems to make use of per default?

Answer (score 1):

This is a daylight savings issue, see the example below.

```r
s <- Sys.time()
as.POSIXct(as.integer(s), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")
#> [1] "2022-07-28 15:05:57 GMT"
as.POSIXct(as.integer(s), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "Europe/London")
#> [1] "2022-07-28 16:05:57 WEST"
s
#> [1] "2022-07-28 16:05:57 BST"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

R's time is the number of seconds since an origin and [time zone](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/timezones.html) and though London and Greenwich are in the same time zone, London's official time is off by 1 hour in this time of year.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if I’m missing a nuance. Regardless of what timezone is associated with the time stamp, why does the filtered time using dplyr not reflect what it should be?